# Matrix Library Update

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm doing a neural network project (much of linear algebra calculations as you know) so I've already used Jblas which is a great library but after I installed Ubuntu latest Version 11.04 I'm having some trouble using it, (error couldn't copy temp bla bla) which I would solve if I did some work.

But the error it self was a warning Should I really use native library ? Knowing that I already escaped C++ because of this kind of errors (Java as portable and Implementation easier etc)

So I went back to Apache Commons which is pretty good (functionally: lots of packages, good design) but performance it's the worst !!

which puts me in dilemma here the Performance in Apache Vs Performance of Processors nowadays Should we disregard the slow performance of Libraries like Apache and count on the Improvement of Technology and multi-threading in new Processors ?

What do you think I should do I'm half way through using JBLAS,

1. Should I use Apache ?
2. Keep going using JBLAs(fix the error) and move on
3. Use another new 2011 promising JAVA linear Algebra library of your choice ?

---

EDIT: Error was:
"org.jblas ERROR Couldn't load copied link file: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jblas2930149998010945438libjblas_arch_flavor.so: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."

After I consulted the Authors of JBLAS at their [Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/jBLAS-Fast-Linear-Algebra-with-Java/123976567969) they told me I would need libgfortran3 to be installed, and problem was solved "Just in case someone gets the same problem"

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of error you're getting, or where. Ubuntu 11 doesn't affect java negatively that I've found.

Comment: It doesn't It affects the JBLAS, I'll come back with the error it self here just 5 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an interpreted language like Java is going to give you the raw performance of native code.  That's why FORTRAN/C/C++ are still very much alive and well in scientific computing.  Packages like LAPACK are still the gold standard as far as I know.

I'm not sure if [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) makes me a liar.  I have no personal experience with it, but if I were still working in this area I'd certainly give it a look.

If that's truly your biggest issue, I'd press on with JBLAS.  You can fix that error.  Keep going.

Comment: Java is not a purely interpreted language. The JVM has a JIT (just-in-time) compiler which compiles bytecode to quite efficient native code. Java is not slow because it is not compiled to native machine code ahead-of-time.

Comment: I realize that Java's not purely interpreted, but that doesn't change the fact that Java hasn't made deep inroads into widespread use for scientific computing.

Comment: If you know it's not a valid argument, then why are you using it? Note: From my own experience I know that the JVM isn't the best platform for raw number crunching. But as far as I know that is because the JVM favors compatability above speed. For example, the trigonometric methods in `java.lang.Math` are implemented in software rather than using the hardware's available functions because that guarantees better that the results are the same on any operating system.

Comment: My argument is still valid.  You sound like you agree with me here.  why are you arguing if your experience agrees with mine and you know that compatibility makes it slower?

Comment: I agree that the JVM is not the best platform for number crunching, but I don't agree that the reason is that Java is (partly) interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) before.  It was created by Mathworks (creators of Matlab) and NIST.  It is a nice packages with basic linear algebra methods, but it may not live up to your speed requirements.